# Swiching to Lubuntu from Ubuntu- Guild Wars 2

Tags: lubuntu, games, ram

If I install Lubuntu over, or in replacement of, the Ubuntu I am already using, can I still download Guild Wars 2 with the play on Linux app? I currently have the game downloaded but it crashes at the login screen trying to load or download more files. I had the game on my laptop before working just fine under windows and finally figured out how to download it again. Or is there another way to suppress unnecessary RAM or something else I can do to make it work better. I just want the easiest and most efficient solution so that I can play my game again.

Answer (score 0):

Wine v1.8 works with Guild Wars 2 but not v1.6 ([Wine Compatibility Information for Guild Wars 2 (64 bit)](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32861&iTestingId=92496)).

I don't know what version of Wine Play-On-Linux uses, but otherwise you'll need to install the package **wine1.8**

[See here for an installation guide for Wine 1.8](http://www.tecmint.com/install-wine-on-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/)

See you at the Black Citadel

**UPDATE**: Sometimes the Guild Wars 2 launcher will freeze the display with the message *Initializing...*, you may be able to work-around this with a custom Wine configuration:

1. Run **winecfg**
2. Click *Add Application*
3. Browse for **Gw2-64.exe**, click *Open*
4. Click *Graphics* tab
5. Check *Emulate a virtual desktop* and specify the same size as your screen
6. Check *Automatically capture the mouse in full-screen windows*
7. Ensure the other two checkboxes (decorate and control) are *not* checked
8. Click *Ok*

You may also need to enable *mouse warp override* if you cannot spin your character around 360 degrees with the mouse and only goes half-way:

1. Run **wine regedit**
2. Navigate to *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\DirectInput*
3. Make sure you're in the *DirectInput* folder
4. From the menu choose *Edit* -> *New* -> *String Value*
5. Enter **MouseWarpOverride** for the name
6. Double-click on it to open the edit dialog for that new entry
7. Enter **enable** in *Value data* and click *OK*
8. Close the registry editor

Comment: Guild Wars looks fully installed. I can get to the log in screen. You know how at the log in screen it shows progress on installing updates? It starts doing that and than freezes so I have to hold the power button to restart. So I think that Ubuntu itself is taking up to much space, but I dont want to go ahead and uninstall it to install Lubuntu if I can't get Guild Wars 2 on it.

Comment: I ran into that problem too, I solved it by adding a custom wine configuration for GW2 to create a virtual desktop.  See my update in the answer.